# Codeception check several elements with same locator

Tags: php, webdriver, codeception

I have several elements on my page with same locator. 
Example:

```
<div.test-info><a>Test1</a></div>
<div.test-info><a>Test2</a></div>
<div.test-info><a>Test3</a></div>
<div.test-info><a>Test4</a></div>
```

There maybe 20 or more elements on the page.

In python, I tested this with FOR loop, which run through array of elements, grabbed by 'findElemenets' method.

My problem is that i don't know how to do this with Codeception.
I found method '_findElements' but it returns Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebElement instances.

Like :

```
Array
  (
      [0] => Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebElement Object
          (
              [executor:protected] => Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteExecuteMethod Object
                  (
                      [driver:Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteExecuteMethod:private] => Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver Object
                          (
                              [executor:protected] => Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor Object
                                  (
                                      [url:protected] => http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
                                      [curl:protected] => Resource id #326
                                  )

                              [sessionID:protected] => 109595b5-f094-4824-ac10-fc7d6353b799
                              [mouse:protected] => 
                              [keyboard:protected] => 
                              [touch:protected] => 
                              [executeMethod:protected] => Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteExecuteMethod Object
   *RECURSION*
                          )

                  )

              [id:protected] => 0
              [fileDetector:protected] => Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\UselessFileDetector Object
                  (
                  )

          )

      [1] => Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebElement Object
          (
              [executor:protected] => Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteExecuteMethod Object
                  (
                      [driver:Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteExecuteMethod:private] => Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver Object
                          (
                              [executor:protected] => Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor Object
                                  (
                                      [url:protected] => http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
                                      [curl:protected] => Resource id #326
                                  )

                              [sessionID:protected] => 109595b5-f094-4824-ac10-fc7d6353b799
                              [mouse:protected] => 
                              [keyboard:protected] => 
                              [touch:protected] => 
                              [executeMethod:protected] => Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteExecuteMethod Object
   *RECURSION*
                          )

                  )

              [id:protected] => 1
              [fileDetector:protected] => Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\UselessFileDetector Object
                  (
                  )

          )

  )
```

How can I operate with this data, or is there another good way to resolve my problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$elements = $I->_findElements('div.test-info a');
foreach($elements as $element)
{
  *do some testing* for example $element->click();
}
```

the methods you can use for the RemoteWebElement, see http://facebook.github.io/php-webdriver/classes/RemoteWebElement.html

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get content of divs, use [grabMultiple](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#grabMultiple) method, it returns array of strings.

`$I->grabMultiple('div.test-info a')`

Comment: Anyway I can't operate with elements. This method returns only text, not exactly the element locator or object. But it can help too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is working solution:

```
$allLinks = $I->grabMultiple('.readmore'); //grab all clickable links

for( $i = 0; $i<sizeof($allLinks); $i++ ) { //iterate through a loop

$I->click($allLinks[$i]); //click each link 

}
```